# clicking a button submits the form instead of showing a p tag in jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form tag that that has two buttons. One to submit and another when clciked needs to reveal a `<p>`.In this case when I click the button it submits the form. For my purpose I need to use form_tag instead of form_for. Here is my code:

```
<%= form_tag treats_path do %>
.
.
.
  <br>
  <div class="i">
  <button class="c">click</button>
  <p class= "d">  lorem ipsum </p>
  </div>

<%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.i').children(".c").on('click', function(){
        $('.d').show();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set `<button type="button">` for this button, because default type for button in form is submit.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm!